# DSL-RAM - Bandwidth Problems

Tags: troubleshooting, terminology

I have an ADSL2+ (Annex B) line, which uses Rate-Adaptive-Mode. It synced fine with 6000/600 kBit/s down/up for 2 years, which resulted in around 6/0.6 MBit download/upload-speed in my LAN. Now, since about a week or so, client download-speed dropped to 2MBit/s while upload remains stable. The router shows a 6000/600 kBit/s down/up sync speed. Nothing changed in cabling to the router and even if you connect it directly onto the phone-line the same symptoms appear.

How does DSL-RAM work?  Can sync with high bandwidth (which is shown in Router/DSLAM, which ISP told me) but software dynamically throttles if the cable is too bad?  Or is the bandwidth shown physically possible at the moment?

Or might this be a hardware-fault?

Comment: Sounds like a SOHO issue and it's nothing we really could do anything about. Talk to your ISP.

Comment: @DanielDib, meta seems to indicate that SOHO is not necessarily off-topic.  Home/consumer is clearly off topic though.  This could be be either.

Comment: Basically this is indeed a SOHO issue, but my main question is if it's somewhere in the DSL-RAM spec, that you can sync with an high bandwidth (which is shown in Router/DSLAM, which ISP told me) but software dynamically throttles if the cable is too bad or if the bandwidth shown is indeed the physically possible at the moment, which would mean throttling on the access server.

Contract specifics are surely not an issue, since it's without bandwidth limitations (new contracts have it and there was a great uproar in Germany) and I had 6 MBit for over two years now.

Comment: Where did you get the data rate from - obtained from modem or told by ISP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try another router/cable/filter and see if the problem remains. If so, probably ISP fault